# Call function in a component created dynamically using ANGULAR

Tags: angular, components, render, dynamically-generated

```
@ViewChild('question', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container!: ViewContainerRef;

editQuestion(){
        const questionFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(FermeeSimpleComponent);
        const questionComponentRef = this.container.createComponent(questionFactory);
        questionComponentRef.instance.add_modalite_simple();
        this.container.insert(questionComponentRef.hostView);
}

HTML :
  <ol class="questions">
    <ng-template #question></ng-template>
  </ol>
```

My code above dynamically creates a component and during this creation calls a function belonging to the created component. This function itself creates a child component.
The component is rendered but the child component is not created. I have the following error:

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')at FermeeSimpleComponent.add_modalite_simple*

I want to display the created component and child component

Answer (score 0):

`componentFactoryResolver` is deprecated

Instead of, you use directly createComponent

```
editQuestion(){
   const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(FermeeSimpleComponent);
   componentRef.instance.add_modalite_simple();
}
```

BTW. I don't know what are your requirements, but sometimes it's more simple use a simple *ngFor or *ngIf to "create" a component, e.g.

```
<ol *ngIf="variable" class="questions">
    <fermee-simple></fermee-simple>
</ol>
```

or

```
components=['simple','complex']

<ol *ngFor="let component of components">
   <fermee-simple *ngIf="component=='simple'"></fermee-simple>
   <fermee-complex *ngIf="component=='complex'"></fermee-complex>
</ol>
```